# How can I play Nintendo 64DD Games with sixtyforce (on Mac)?

Tags: emulation, nintendo, nintendo-64, nintendo-64dd

[64DD.org](http://64dd.org/index.html) has some game dumps and information on how to play 64DD games in MAME or Project64.  Is there any way to play 64DD dumps on a Mac using [sixtyforce](http://sixtyforce.com/) (my version is registered)?  I was thinking about sending Gerrit Goossen an email about adding support as a feature request or asking to help with code the 64DD IPL support.

If not, what are my options?  Can I build the source of Project64 on Mac if sixtyforce does not support 64DD dumps?

Comment: Does it allow you to open a ROM file when you launch the application? If not, I'm sure Mupen64 would work. I don't have a lot of experience with emulation on a mac. There is always the dosbox option, but it sounds redundant to launch an emulator through dosbox that runs on a mac...

Comment: I've tried emailing Gerrit about a few things before, and have never received a response :( Sixtyforce is a great emulator, but sometimes goes years without an update.

Comment: @KenD I've done the same as well with no response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use Sixtyforce, it doesn't support N64DD ROMs.

However, an alternative I'm looking into is using [MAME](https://64dd.org/tutorial_mame.html) to play N64DD titles on my MacOS machine.

Comment: No, the bit about sixtyforce not supporting those ROMs is certainly useful, it's just it would be a lot more useful with the extra stuff :-) I'll remove the details to follow bit but it'd still be a better answer if you add them or even just state whether it worked for you or not.

Comment: You didn't explain what Sixtyforce is, and "you can't" is not an amazing answer. Not to be aggressive, by any means.

Comment: This answer now has received an NAA flag.  I'm inclined to leave it as the mention of MAME is an answer.  You may wish to remove the Sixtyforce mention from the answer.  It may be better to mention Sixtyforce as being not useful in the question.

Answer (score 4):

My recommendation what be to use [Bizhawk](http://tasvideos.org/BizHawk.html). It's an Emulator that was originally designed for TASing (Tool Assisted Speedrunning, see [tasvideos.org](http://tasvideos.org) for details), however it's come a long way since it was first being developed, and now is mostly used for emulating pretty much everything (at least that I can think of), including Nintendo 64DD games, assuming that you've downloaded and added the firmware (https://www.retroroms.info/forum/topic/BizHawk-2-0-firmware.htm).

Keep in mind that a huge advantage to using Multi-Emulators is that you can get used to one menu/GUI, and have it there for everything you play.